# Макрос-функция

Tags: c

Как в Си определить многострочный макрос, который будет работать как в функция. То есть было

```
int abs(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        return -x;
    else
        return x;
}
```

а стало

```
#define abs(x) ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\ - в конце строки продолжает строку на следующую за ней.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
#define ABS(x) ( (x < 0) ? -x : x )
```

К слову, сделать это без конструкций и операторов языка не получится, т.к. макросы работают только на этапе компиляции.